# Can I revert from using techeiles back to using all-white strings?

Tags: minhag, tzitzis, techeles

I used to wear all-white tzitzis, as is the more "universal" custom.

Some time ago, I was convinced to start wearing a blue thread in them, to fulfill the commandment in the Torah to insert a psil techeiles.

Later, I concluded that we do not have a mesorah for techeiles and therefore the companies which manufacture techeiles nowadays do not have the "real deal" dye from the chilazon.

I switched back to using all-white strings.

Did I act properly? Is one allowed to revert to using all-white strings when he decided to put a blue thread in it as the Torah commands? One possible problem I see is that we never go down in holiness, but rather only up (maalah b'kedushah v'lo matah).

In my case I believed initially the blue dye was the real deal, but later concluded that it was not. This case does not deal with someone who believed, and continues to believe, the blue dye we have today is indeed from the chilazon, but yet wears all-white strings anyway for whatever reason. I believe such a question would have to be asked separately.

Notice: I'd like to avoid confrontation about rather the techeiles we have today (be it from the murex trunculus or the cuttlefish) being the real deal. That is not what this question is about; and trust me - I've read into the whole thing. I'm familiar with the arguments.

Comment: Why do you think this would be more of a problem than not wearing tekhelet in general?

Comment: techielies is not a minhag ,you are either trying to fulfill a Torah obligation or not,if you beileve its the real thing or a safek then why would you switch back,and if you were concived that its not true techieleis at all then whats even the q?

Comment: Remember to include motivation in the post itself.

Comment: Not your motivation for wanting to revert back. Your motivation for asking — meaning: why is this at all a question that anyone would be interested in? (Answer: because [you say] _t'cheles_ in _tzitzis_ may count as a _minhag_ nowadays and perhaps _halachos_ could get more complicated when one changes his minhag and then reverts.) **That's** what you should [edit] in to the question.

Comment: "It could be argued that techeiles is more of a minhag today." I don't see how that could be argued. @sam is totally right.

Comment: may be that you weared tchelet by misyake, without knowing that your rabonim are not advising this

Comment: R' Halberstam of Khal Chassidim deLakewood holds that Ptil Tekhelet techeilet is authentic and that we should force people to wear it (as with any other mitzvat 'aseh)

Comment: Here's the shi'ur: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3k6TIbx2XKk&t=606s

Comment: The long and short of it is: if you wear techeiles, it's not kale ilan, since it's not plant-based. So the worst you do is get extremely expensive tzitzis. If we're wrong, we're still fulfilling the mitzvoh, whereas if the halocho is like Revi, then wearing white doesn't even fulfil the base requirement lechatchilo, only bedi'eved (Menachos 38a). I'll b"n turn this into an answer.

Comment: Friends, I have edited the question body to make it better.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're assuming the currently available blues are wrong. Ok. So what could possibly be gained by wearing it? How is wearing a nonsense string a higher level of holiness? Maybe you'd have a question if you changed from thinking it was Vadai right to Safek right. But as currently posed there's nothing here.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt When the gemara said kala ilan, that was just an example. If someone used a different dye, it would be the same issue.

Comment: I asked a chashuve posek in E"Y if I could stop wearing techeiles, and he said yes (so long as it wouldn't cause any family dispute). He added, though, that because a lot of people wear it or don't wear it for social/political reasons, that he doesn't like when people go back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

A very similiar situation arises in the area of Chalav Stam and Chalav Yisroel. In Igros Moshe Yoreh Deah 1:47 Reb Moshe says it depends if the person was being makpid knowing that it was a chumra, in which case he would need to be matir neder. If he was doing it because he felt the Halacha was that it is assur and now he finds out it is not assur then he does not need to be matir neder. Your situation seems quite similiar. If you were wearing it as a chumra then hataras nedarim would be in order, if you did it because you thought the halacha was that it was required and now you became convinced that the halacha is different, then you do not need the hataras nedarim.

Here is [the teshuva](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=81) of Reb Moshe

Comment: I'm not sure this logic applies here to an asei. If you realize later the milk was heter because the gezera doesn't apply, your until-now chumra is still a chumra that makes sense (one can always choose to be strict to avoid permitted things for some given chashash) and hence your chumra would persist until broken by hatarat nedarim. But if you realize later the dye was not tekhelet then your until-now chumra is just nonsense and doesn't persist since it never existed.

Comment: That's why I included the part that if it's because you realize that the halacha is different, then you don't need hataras nedarim

Comment: But you said "If you were wearing it as a chumra then hataras nedarim would be in order"

Comment: I added that in out of deference to the other answer that said that you need to be matir neder, although it can't be a chumra, theoretically it could be a minhag tov that would also need hataras nedarim

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Be mattir neder first just in case, the same as any other custom that a person takes on and then wants to abandon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have a source?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76375/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-reverting-from-techeiles-back-to-white).